# Is it possible to talk to AIM users with any Jabber client via any jabber account?

Tags: jabber, xmpp, aim

Are the network and protocol fully and unqualifiedly interoperable? If so, how do you do it? Just screen-name@aol.com? Or @aim.com? I'm aware that it's possible with gmail, but I want to know if this is a special arrangement (it definitely used to be) or whether there's full XMPP compatibility in the AIM network.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The `aim.com` domain has no SRV records for `_xmpp-server._tcp` at all, which means it doesn't support XMPP federation.

The `aol.com` domain *does* have SRV records for server-to-server XMPP communications:

```
$ host -t SRV _xmpp-server._tcp.aol.com
_xmpp-server._tcp.aol.com has SRV record 0 1 5269 xmpp.gxmpp.oscar.aol.com.
```

And according to a [post on the pidgin-devel list](http://pidgin.im/pipermail/devel/2011-May/021876.html) (dated May 2011),

> AIM users can IM "whoever at gmail.com."  The first IM will fail to go
>   through and the Google Talk user will get an authorization request.
>   After the auth request is accepted, messages from the AIM user to the
>   Google Talk user go through.  And Google Talk users can IM
>   "screenname at aol.com" or "email(domain.com)@aol.com"

However, neither `grawity@aol.com` nor `grawity(aim.com)@aol.com` were recognized by Gmail for me, and AIM similarly refused to send anything to `grawity@gmail.com`. I'm not sure if this is related to me having switched to Hangouts, or if the federation was just switched off.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. But you only addressed google<->aim interaction... What about instant messaging between non-google-affiliated XMPP accounts and AIM accounts?